AEM Sling Model Re-usability
I have a unique requirement in AEM Cloud project to re-use the custom sling model with multiple custom components.
I created, tested this thoroughly and everything working as expected but want to make sure anyone else tried this approach before with AEM. I know this is little out of way implementation for custom component general structure. This project has huge number of components and this pattern helps me to avoid creating hundreds of component specific duplicate sling models as the properties are mostly same with different HTMLs. I don't want to create as variants as they fall into different content groups for better authoring experience. Below is the scenario.
Sling Model:
standardContent.java with properties Title, Description, image, video, buttons
Component 1:
<div class="comp1" data-sly-use.model="com.project.core.models.standardContent">
 // Component specific HTML based on DESIGN which is totally different behavior than comp 2 & 3
</div>

Component 2:
<div class="comp2" data-sly-use.model="com.project.core.models.**standardContent**">
// Component specific HTML based on DESIGN which is totally different behavior than comp 1 & 3
</div>

Component 3:
<div class="comp3" data-sly-use.model="com.project.core.models.standardContent">
// Component specific HTML based on DESIGN which is totally different behavior than comp 1 & 2
</div>


Another useful way to do this, rather than a single sling model, is that you can have multiple sling models in the same component. If the various behaviors are in groups - like for example, many components have a color, size, rotation, you can make a sling model for appearance; and many components have a list of elements, you can make a sling model for that, too. Since it's unlikely there would be a change in color depending on the number of elements in the list, they won't need to inter-operate.
This kind of composition can also take the place of abstract classes and inheritance in some cases, and be easier to read.

You should be able to do something like this if you have your sling model to work differently depending on the type of resource that is being adapted, the best place to have this type of check would be on a PostConstruct method. I wouldn't advice on doing this though because this code will continue to grow depending on how many components you have, I would recommend to better have an abstract class that has generic functionality that could apply to all of your components and then inherit from it maybe even a better solution would be to consider registering an adapter factory but it would depends on the specific requirements for your project.
